# Call a function in window.onresize. (scope)

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a constructor object. Inside this constructor i have two functions. One is called **window.onresize** and the other one is **onBrowserResize**. Now i want to call **onBrowserResize** inside the **window.onresize** function. How do i do this?

```
function MyObject() {
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        this.onBrowserResize();
    }

    this.onBrowserResize = function() {
    }
}
```

I would like to have the function public so i can call it like this: `object.onBrowserResize();`

If I make the function private like this: `var onBrowserResize = function()` then I cannot access it outside the scope.

Anyone has an idea how to do it? I'm probably just a bit confused about the scoping in objects.

Comment: @Magus window is the browser window so not a variable that i made up. So when i get in the window function this will refer to window instead of my object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` is determined depending on how the function is called. See [the MDN article on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for details.

Your question is missing some details. My answer is assuming you have something like this:

```
var MyObj = function() {
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        this.onBrowserResize();
    }

    this.onBrowserResize = function() {}
}
```

Which is instanced like this:

```
var myObj = new MyObj();
```

Here are some of ways to achieve that.

**1. Just passing this.onBrowserResize** as the event handler (the simplest way to go, if all your onresize handler does is call `onBrowserResize`):

```
var MyObj = function() {
    window.onresize = this.onBrowserResize;
    this.onBrowserResize = function() {
        // caution: "this" here won't be your object.
        // use option 3 below if you need this to be your object
    }
}
```

**2. Caching a reference to the local `this`**:

```
var MyObj = function() {
    var that = this;
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        that.onBrowserResize();
    }

    this.onBrowserResize = function() {}
}
```

**3. Fixing the value of `this` with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**:

```
var MyObj = function() {
    window.onresize = this.onBrowserResize.bind(this);

    this.onBrowserResize = function() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i used option two cause i thought it looked the cleanest. Is this a common problem people have and fix this way?

Comment: Yes, it is very common, due to the way `this` behaves in js. A little strange if you're used to a traditional class-based language, but you get used to it... If you use option #3, you won't have any surprises (i.e., `this` inside `onBrowserResize` will be your object, not `window` as in the other 2 options).

Answer (score 1):

```
//Constructor Object
function MyObject(){

};

MyObject.prototype.onWindowResize = function(){
  this.onBrowserResize();
}

MyObject.prototype.onBrowserResize = function(){

}

   //Implementation
   var myObject = new MyObject();
   myObject.onWindowResize();
   myObject.onBrowserResize();
```

Comment: Thanks but i mean the window.onresize function not onWindowResize.